# Couchbase-exporter starting issue for grafana

Tags: database, couchbase, grafana, prometheus

While starting couchbase-exporter as per the document getting below error.

> WARN[0000] couldn't verify server version compatibility: failed to get nodes: failed to get /pools/nodes metrics: 401 source="couchbase.go:34"
>
> ERRO[0457] failed to scrape cluster                      error="failed to get cluster: failed to get /pools/default metrics:  401" source="cluster.go:267"
>
> ERRO[0457] failed to scrape nodes                        error="failed to get nodes: failed to get /pools/nodes metrics:  401" source="node.go:178"
>
> ERRO[0457] failed to scrape buckets                      error="failed to get buckets: failed to get /pools/default/buckets metrics:  401" source="bucket.go:1437"
>
> ERRO[0457] failed to scrape tasks                        error="failed to get tasks: failed to get /pools/default/tasks metrics:  401" source="task.go:130"

Please help!Thanks

Comment: What is couchbase-exporter? Do you mean cbexport? Can you provide the command you executed?

Comment: Issue resolved as I have mentioned in my answer. Issue was coming due to wrong user/password while running command.